# exercise involving exactness

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I have been stuck on this exercise for a little while.
We are in abelian category. How do I show that 
$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B$ is exact if and only if
$f: A \rightarrow B$ is a monomorphism?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume here monomorphism only means left-cancelable?

Comment: I am guessing that is what I have (as I don't know what left-cancelable is). The definition I have here is that if I have $\mu:X \rightarrow A$, $\mu':X \rightarrow A$ and $f \mu = f \mu'$ implies $\mu = \mu'$. Thanks!

Comment: The definition of exactness says the kernel of $A \to B$ vanishes. Show this implies that $A \to B$ is a monomorphism.